# Phonegap iOS push plugin issues

Tags: xcode, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I've been following this article [link](https://medium.com/@anjana.pai.rathod/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-ios-using-phonegap-or-cordova-and-java-8ebf95ccdd9e) but the latest version of that plugin is causing several issues and seems to have lots of overhead, Cocoa Pods install etc.  We have our own APNS server, I just need the token and to register for notifications.

The plugin I'm using phonegap-plugin-push installs fine but when I open the workspace in XCode I get an error that it can't open my main project because it is open from another project.  I only have one instance of XCode running.

Comment: Found a fix, you must have XCode closed when you add the plugin because cocoa pods build will mess up.  I removed the platform ios and readded it with XCode closed.

Comment: Okay. SO now which error are you facing ?

Comment: Everything works now, just have to remember to close xcode

Comment: Okay. So the issue is solved now. Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close XCode and reinstall the plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this plugin

```
   <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="1.8.4">
      <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="XXXXXXX" />
   </plugin>
```